# Track and administer OpenID permissions on Google account

Tags: google-account, openid, permissions

How do I track and administer all my OpenID permissions on my Google account? For example, I signed in to an OpenID-enabled site. If it was a new site I visited, I'd get a permission request page to link the site's OpenID mechanism to my Google account.

> Now, if I could *give* permission, that surely means I can *revoke* it?

How do I do it on my Google account?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to https://www.google.com/accounts/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens

To navigate to this page:

- Sign in at http://google.com and click your name in the top navigation bar. Then go to **Google Account Settings**.
- At the bottom, click **Visit the previous version of the Google accounts screen**.
- In the **Security** section under the **Personal Settings** tab, click **Authorizing Applications & Sites**
- It then displays a list of sites under the **Connected Sites, Apps, and Services** header which you can then Revoke Access to.